# Program tries to change user hard limit so I can execute it just by root but not with regular users

Tags: permissions, users, ulimit

I installed a program that tries to change my hard limits (I've figured it out because the only error that it is showing is `limit: coredumpsize: Can't set limit` and using root I'm able to execute it) but I want to start it using my regular user of course.

I already tried to log in with root and remove limits using `ulimit -c unlimited` but it still does not work.
The strangest thing is that the program works with my regular user on Debian (on my laptop) but not on Ubuntu (on my desktop). Both are 64bit system and the installation is exactly the same.

Is there any way that I could start this program without being root?

NB: The entire installation is in `/opt/` and is owned by my regular user (I confined it using apparmor but all my tests were with aa stopped).

Comment: `ulimit` is a (bash, zsh at least) shell builtin, AFAIK it only applies to the current shell (and processes started from it) - so I don't think running it as root will help. Have you tried executing `ulimit -c unlimited` as your normal user before starting the program?

Comment: normal users can't do that: they can just change soft limit up to the hard limit.

Comment: Yes, but the hard limit is unlimited AFAIK - at least, I've always been able to set core size unlimited as user. Unless this is not an Ubuntu system? Or you have modified /etc/security/limits.conf?

Comment: No, I didn't change it... and it is Ubuntu (maybe it has something to do with the fact it is ubuntu-studio?)

Comment: What exactly happens? does the user `ulimit` refuse to change, or does changing it not make any difference to whether the program works?

Comment: My output for `ulimit -c unlimited` called by normal user is :

Comment: `bash: ulimit: core file size: impossibile modificare il limite: Operazione non permessa` which means that my normal user can't do that because have not permissions for it. (sorry for double comment, i'm not able to edit my comment)

Comment: Hmm that is different from what I've seen on regular Ubuntu (12.04 thru 16.04). Have you actually looked at the /etc/security/limits.conf file (plus any relevant files in /etc/security/limits.d)?

Comment: Yes, I did... now I'm trying changing it by setting up hard limit to unlimited in that file just for my normal user by editing that file to check if it works.

Comment: Even adding the string `user hard core unlimited` to that file, my output says my hard limit for core file size is still 0... any ideas to solve this?

Comment: For now I solved it by using a launch script containing: `export processpid="$$"; su -l root -c "prlimit --pid $processpid --core=0:unlimited"; program-to-launch"`. But I hate having to type every time the root password for a normal user command...